# Вывод несколько кнопок

Tags: php

Есть функция с кнопками:

```
    function column_order_actio($item){

        $actions['order-delete'] = sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&order_id=%d">Удалить</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], 'order-delete', $item->order_id);
        
        if($item->order_status == 1){
            $salaries = array(); 
            $salaries = sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&order_id=%d&order_status=%d">Неоплачен</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], 'status-switch', $item->order_id, '2');
            $salaries = sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&order_id=%d&order_status=%d">Пригласительный</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], 'status-switch', $item->order_id, '6');
            $salaries = sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&order_id=%d&order_status=%d">Бронь кассира</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], 'status-switch', $item->order_id, '4');
    
            foreach($salaries as $val_arr){
                echo $result = $val_arr ."<br />";
            }
        }else if($item->order_status == 2){
            echo $result = sprintf('<a class="" href="?page=%s&action=%s&order_id=%d&order_status=%d">Оплачен</a>');
        }else if($item->order_status == 3){
            echo $result = sprintf('<a class="" href="?page=%s&action=%s&order_id=%d&order_status=%d">Оплачен</a><br><a class="" href="?page=%s&action=%s&order_id=%d&order_status=6">Неоплачен</a>');
        }

        return sprintf('%1$s %2$s', $this->row_actions($actions), $result);
            
    }
```

Нужно вывести только определённые кнопки, при определённом статусе заказа.
Единственное решение с наименьшим использованием кода которое удалось найти в интернете, это использовать foreach. Но, не совсем понимаю, как тогда вызвать в итоге через return

Comment: у `sprintf` есть свои прелести, но как способ подставить внутрь строки переменные это самый медленный из возможных способов. а salaries у вас строка, которую вы постоянно перезаписываете

Comment: вы лучше словами опишите, что хотите из чего получить. потому что данный код понять сложно.

Comment: Как и написал выше, мне нужно вывести определённые (несколько) кнопки при определённом статусе заказа. Но главное чтобы всё  это вызывалось через конечный ```return sprintf('%1$s %2$s', $this->row_actions($actions), $result);```

Comment: В данной функции есть ещё код, он был изначально там: `$result = array();
        for($a = 1; $a<=3; $a++){
            if($item->order_status == $a) 
                continue;
                $result['update-status-'.$a] = sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&order_id=%d&order_status=%d">'.evpl_get_status_name($a).'</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'status-switch',$item->order_id,$a);
            }` Но данный код выводил и менял местами только две кнопки, при статусе 1 и 2 у заказа. А нужно добавить ещё несколько.

Comment: c salaries я уже понял проблему. @teran

Comment: там в прицнипе не надо складывать это добро в массив, чтоыб потом проходить по нему и делать конкатенацию. можно сразу делать `$result .= ...`. `echo` в коде явно не нужны, если вы хотите вернуть результат из функции. В куче sprintf ваших не везде есть параметры. Вообще чтобы собрьать URL для ссылки можно использовать `http_build_query`, описав параметры в виде массива, это хотя бы читабельно будет.

Comment: `Нужно вывести только определённые кнопки, при определённом статусе заказа` попробуйте конструкцию `switch($status)` или даже банальный массив `$x = [оплачен, не оплачен, бронь, etc]; echo "<a href='#'>". $x[$status]. "</a>"`. а вообще printf, sprintf, echo использовать в логике - так себе затея, хотя бы заливайте весь вывод конкатенацией в какую нибудь $out и в самом конце юзайте `die($out);` такой подход много нервов спасёт в будущем, когда возьметесь за заголовки, сессии, кукиши =)

Answer (score 1):

если хочется оформить это хоть мало-мальски конфигурируемо и понятно, то берете делаете массив в котором описываете общие параметры и кнопки

```
$commonParams = [
   'page' => $_REQUEST['page'], 
   'order_id' => ..., 
];
$conf = [
   'action1' => [
      'title' => "title1", 
      'params' => ['action' => 'some-action']
   ],
   'action2' => [....],
];
```

Далее конфигурацию кнопок в зависимости от входящего параметра, где будут ключи - статусы, значения - коды кнопок (ключи массива конфигурации):

```
$links = [
    1 => ['action1', 'action2'],
    2 => ['action3']
];
```

Далее возьмите маленькую функцию для генерации ссылки

```
$makeLink = function($config) {
     $url = http_build_query($commonParmas + $config['params']);
     return "<a href='?{$url}'>{$config['title']}</a>"; 
}
```

Потом берете текущий  набор кнопок, и генерируете ссылки по конфигу

```
$currentBtnSet = $links[$item->orderStatus];
$result = "";
foreach ($currentBtnSet as $btn) {
   $result .= $makeLink($conf[$btn]);
}
```

и наконец возвращаете полученное. Если надо добавить еще что-то там для удаления, то делаете

```
$delete = ...;

return "{$delete}<br/>{$result}"
```

Comment: Страница на сайте не открывается...

Comment: В логах нашёл `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$currentBtnSet' (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: и что вы самостоятельно не можете добавить точку с запятой в код?